# Using VBA Match and Index function

Tags: vba, indexing, match, case

Trying to use match & Index with specified ranges. Does not recognise RefreshDrNumbers in the code.

I am using the Case Function to specify ranges.

Can't seem to make the Case, Match & Index function connect or talk to each other?

The other Forum I've asked is

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/add-ranges-to-match-and-index-functions.1162701/

```
Private Sub Jobcard_Demands_Click()

     If Jobcard_Demands = ("Drawing No`s Update") Then

    Dim matchRange As Range
    Dim ODict As Object
    Dim PartsListLastRow As Long, DestLastRow As Long
    Dim LookupRange As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Parts List")
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Card Master")
    
    PartsListLastRow = wsSource.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    DestLastRow = wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'This holds the lookup range (including both the lookup key
    'column and the value column)
    Set matchRange = wsSource.Range("E1:F" & PartsListLastRow)
    
    'Get a dictionary of all the lookup values. The function, as
    'defined below, takes the range as well as the relative column
    'of the keys and values. In our case, the first column of our
    'range has the keys, and the second has the values
    Set ODict = GetDictionary(matchRange, 5, 6)
    
    'Below, define the lookup range. In your specific code, this
    'varies based on the combobox value, but I think you'll be able
    'to figure out how to define it (I'm just hardcoding mine
    Set LookupRange = wsDest.Range("A1:A" & DestLastRow)
    
    'Loop over the lookup range
    For i = 1 To DestLastRow
        'Since the GetPartInfo function handles cases where there isn't a match
        ' (it returns a blank string), you don't have to use an if/else statement
        wsDest.Range("B" & i).Value = GetPartInfo(ODict, wsDest.Range("E" & i).Value)
    Next i
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetDictionary(rng As Range, keyCol As Long, valCol As Long) As Object
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim ODict As Object
    
    Set sht = rng.Parent
    Set ODict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For Each rCell In rng.Columns(keyCol).Cells
        If Not ODict.Exists(rCell.Offset(, keyCol - 1).Value) Then
            ODict.Add rCell.Offset(, keyCol - 1).Value, rCell.Offset(, valCol - 1).Value
        End If
    Next rCell
    
    Set GetDictionary = ODict
End Function

'This is just a helper function to de-clutter the main subroutine. Returns an
' empty string in cases where the part doesn't exist in the dictionary
Private Function GetPartInfo(ByRef ODict As Object, sKey As String)
    Dim Output As String
    
    Output = ""
    
    If ODict.Exists(sKey) Then
        Output = ODict(sKey)
    End If
    
    GetPartInfo = Output
End Function
```

Comment: what is `RefreshDrNumbers`? is that a function?  If so, can you paste it also?

Comment: The idea was to use it in the code below Subtitle to tie the 2 together. I have done it before and it worked?

Comment: `RefreshDrNumbers` is not native vba, so it must be a function somewhere in the workbook.  Maybe where you were using it, it existed and does not exist here.

Comment: When you say native VBA what would you recommend to make it work?

Comment: You will need to find the function or addin that was being used in the other workbook and add it to this workbook.  Outside that we cannot help.

Comment: You need to add arguments to `RefreshDrNumbers()` to pass in said ranges, so `myFunction(r as excel.range)` and call like `myFunction worksheets(1).range("a1:c100")`

Comment: You're going to run into scope issues. A number of the variables that you call in the `RefreshDrNumbers()` function are scoped to the `Refresh_Drawing_Numbers_Click` sub

Comment: Would it be possible to take the lower sub away somehow?

Comment: https://www.excelanytime.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=161:excel-vba-passing-arguments-to-procedures-parameter-arrays-paramarray&catid=79&Itemid=475    and   https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/variable-scope.html

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I'm working with code that performs many lookups over the same range, I tend to package that lookup range into a dictionary. Lookups in a dictionary are highly efficient, so you don't have to worry about the "cost" of the lookup. There is an overhead to populate the dictionary, but this is often recovered as the number of lookups grows.

I took that approach in the below solution. I use helper functions to create the dictionary and to lookup dictionary values. This helps to declutter the main routine. See if you can work with the code below, and adapt it to your solution. I commented it where I felt it would add value, and I think you should be able to adapt to your needs. Write back with any issues.

```
Sub RefreshStuff()
    Dim matchRange As Range
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lookupRange As Range
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    
    'This holds the lookup range (including both the lookup key
    'column and the value column)
    Set matchRange = Sheets("Parts List").Range("E1:F6")
    
    'Get a dictionary of all the lookup values. The function, as
    'defined below, takes the range as well as the relative column
    'of the keys and values. In our case, the first column of our
    'range has the keys, and the second has the values
    Set oDict = GetDictionary(matchRange, 1, 2)
    
    'Below, define the lookup range. In your specific code, this
    'varies based on the combobox value, but I think you'll be able
    'to figure out how to define it (I'm just hardcoding mine
    lastRow = 10
    Set wsDest = Sheets("Job Card Master")
    Set lookupRange = wsDest.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    
    'Loop over the lookup range
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        'Since the GetPartInfo function handles cases where there isn't a match
        ' (it returns a blank string), you don't have to use an if/else statement
        wsDest.Range("B" & i).Value = GetPartInfo(oDict, wsDest.Range("A" & i).Value)
    Next i
End Sub


Private Function GetDictionary(rng As Range, keyCol As Long, valCol As Long) As Object
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim oDict As Object
    
    Set sht = rng.Parent
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For Each rCell In rng.Columns(keyCol).Cells
        If Not oDict.exists(rCell.Offset(, keyCol - 1).Value) Then
            oDict.Add rCell.Offset(, keyCol - 1).Value, rCell.Offset(, valCol - 1).Value
        End If
    Next rCell
    
    Set GetDictionary = oDict
End Function

'This is just a helper function to de-clutter the main subroutine. Returns an
' empty string in cases where the part doesn't exist in the dictionary
Private Function GetPartInfo(ByRef oDict As Object, sKey As String)
    Dim output As String
    
    output = ""
    
    If oDict.exists(sKey) Then
        output = oDict(sKey)
    End If
    
    GetPartInfo = output
End Function
```

Comment: I tried your code but it`s not working. Gets to Set match range then stops?

Comment: I Have sent my workbook to you so you can see what's going on. Link above. I am sure your code will work but there's properly some mistake of mine?

Comment: @user14435479 I don't want to leave you in the lurch on this, but I can't actually download external files on my work computer. Can you give any feedback about what's happening when it hits the `Set matchRange` line? Does it throw an error? Can you step through the code to see if there's a specific deviant record that's causing a problem?

Comment: The set matchrange = Nothing

Comment: @user14435479 That's strange since we are simple assigning a range to a variable. Is the sheet name correct (no typos)? Are you hardcoding your range (for example, E1:F6), or are you taking a dynamic approach?

Comment: Dynamic Range see below. Sheet names are correct

Comment: Set matchRange = wsSource.Range("E1:F" & PartsListLastRow)

Comment: Can you test the value of `PartsListLastRow` when the code fails?

Comment: @user14435479 Would you be able to edit your original post and just copy and paste your code, as you have it?

Comment: I`ve added the new code to the original post

Comment: @user14435479 I think I found the issue. In your code line ` Set ODict = GetDictionary(matchRange, 5, 6)`, you should actually be using ` Set ODict = GetDictionary(matchRange, 1, 2)`. The way I set up the function to load the dictionary, it takes the relative columns within the range. Since our range is E1:F1252, we want the key column to be the first in that range, and the values to be the second column of that range. I think you entered them as the 5th and 6th columns of the worksheet. Try that and see if it works out.

Comment: @user14435479 I downloaded the workbook to my PC, and it seems that the code is working. So, we should make sure we have matching logic. The code currently loops over column E in `Job Card Master`, and looks up corresponding values in Column E in `Parts List`. Is this actually what you want? I tried to manually look up individual parts names from one sheet to the other, and the random sampling that I looked up wasn't actually found. Do we have mismatched columns? Do we have a miscommunications?